# "Bad value for attribute src on element img: Must be non-empty", for dynamically generated img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, w3c-validation

I have a web site with an image slider. I keep the some of the image tags empty as the images load on when slide comes into view for faster page load. The image tags defined as follows:

```
<img data-src="img/portfolio-desktop1-small.png" src="" alt=""/>
```

What I'm doing is on slide function I change the `src` to `data-src` with jQuery animation. The slider works great. My problem is when I try to validate it in [w3c validation tool](https://validator.w3.org/) it gives the following error:

> Line 131, Column 179: Bad value for attribute `src` on element `img`: Must be non-empty.
>
> ```
> ...data-src="img/portfolio-desktop1-small.jpg" src="" alt=""/>
> ```
>
> Syntax of URL:
>   Any URL. For example: `/hello`, `#canvas`, or `http://example.org/`. > Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as `%20`.

Is there anyway to fix this without altering the JavaScript or CSS? If I leave it like this what can be the possible harmful outcomes of this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you just remove the src attribute then add it on the fly when you need it. The src attribute isn't required. And in my opinion I wouldn't worry about what the w3c validation tool says anyway. As long as you test it in the necessary browsers and it works.

Comment: Removing `src`  gave me the a different error which is:
>Line 131, Column 172: Element img is missing required attribute src.
though I guess I have to agree with you that at the moment w3c validation is not good enough to worry right now.

Comment: Sounds like the validation tool is just a fickle bitch. I'd say just cross browser test it to ensure nothing is broken and call it a day.

Comment: The [`src` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src) *is* required.

Comment: @unor technically yes but on browsers I care about it doesn't break.

Answer (score 11):

Set the image `src` attribute to `#`:

```html
<img data-src="img/portfolio-desktop1-small.png"
   src="#" alt="Thumbnail">
```

The HTML passes the W3C validator just fine, and modern browsers know not to try to load the non-existent image.*

For contrast, using a `src` value that references a non-existent file results in an unnecessary HTTP request and an error:

```html
<img data-src="img/portfolio-desktop1-small.png"
   src="bogus.png" alt="Thumbnail">
```

> Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.

*Note: *I've read conflicting information on how browsers handle the `#`.  If anyone has definitive information, please add a comment.*

Also see related answer by *sideshowbarker* about the `action` attribute:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491636

#### Update: *November 2022*

It seems the `src="#"` trick used to be a decent workaround but it's no longer a good idea to send that to the browser. 
So, I created a build tool to convert occurrences of `src="#"` in source HTML to inline [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) of a tiny invisible one pixel SVG appropriate for the browser.

**Build tool `img-src-placeholder`:**
https://github.com/center-key/img-src-placeholder (MIT License)

The interesting bits are:

```js
const onePixelSvg =
   '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1" height="1"></svg>';
const dataImage = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' +
   Buffer.from(onePixelSvg).toString('base64');
html.replace(/src=["']?#["']?/gm, `src="${dataImage}"`);
```

The resulting HTML will have `<img>` tags like:

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiPjwvc3ZnPg=="
   alt=avatar>
```

The advantage of using a build tool is that:

1. Source remains uncluttered
2. HTML always validates
3. The inline data URL prevents the browser from making an unnecessary and invalid network request

Comment: I've just tried this in Chrome, and loads the current URL (html) again for each image with src="#", so that won't work for me.

Comment: @ernesto Can you look in the console and verify that the 404 error you're seeing has a `#` in the URL just to make sure it's not another image resource that's having trouble loading (it's working ok for me with Chrome v55.0.2883.95 on macOS 10.12.2).

Comment: I'm not seeing a 404. I'm seeing the base href (document URL) being fetched again for every image (or at least once).

Answer (score 2):

**Update Jan 2021.**  The src="#" trick works now on the validator at https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for the answer, the `src="/"` code resolves the w3c validator complains and doesn't produce additional request like the solution with the `#` character.