# javascript click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I'm having trouble figuring out why my click event is not firing. I am trying to click on the trash can icon and have a function run that deletes the list element. After the click event, it fails to execute anything else in the script. It doesn't even console.log anything directly below. Below is the markup and my script.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="js-list-item">
        <h3 class="js-list-title"></h3>
        <a href="" id="js-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href=""id="js-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <p>Date: <span class="js-date"></span></p>
        <p>Schedule: <span class="js-schedule"></span> at <span class="js-schedule-time">
        </span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript code**

```
function handleDelete() {
$('.js-list-item').on('click', 'fa-trash-o', function(e) {
    console.log('test');
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteShow(
        $(e.currentTarget).closest('.js-list-item').attr('id')
    );
});
}
```

Comment: Do you have JQuery loaded?

Comment: Check console logs in browser

Comment: Where is the `deleteShow()` function?

Comment: When is your function handleDelete called? You need to execute that function first for binding the listener

Comment: handleDelete is called at the bottom of the file, like so.
    $(function() {
    handleDelete();});

Comment: deleteShow() is an ajax delete request, but it isn't even trying to execute it. I have the console.log directly below it to test if it's even getting to the next line and it is not. After the click fires it stops trying to do anything else. I put a breakpoint to confirm

Comment: try adding a dot to the selector parameter `.fa-trash-o`

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter of the `.on()` function is a selector.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Change:

`$('.js-list-item').on('click', 'fa-trash-o', function(e) {`

to:

`$('.js-list-item').on('click', '.fa-trash-o', function(e) {`

Comment: @Jameson, also add a space to change `<a href=""id="js-delete">` to `<a href="" id="js-delete">`.  Or even better: `<a href=# id="js-delete">`.  The `#` tells modern browsers not to actually load the page on click.  Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834047

Answer (score 0):

('click', 'fa-trash-o', function(e)

fa-trash-o is not a proper selector, use class or id